# Beaglebone Black with Nodejs: Error: Module did not self-register

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, npm, beagleboneblack

I was trying to run 'node app.js' command to it and I'm using Ubuntu. After that I upgraded my nodejs version on my Beaglebone black, I found out after I run it, I have this error when performing js function

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bonescript/node_modules/ffi/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:83
    throw e
    ^

Error: Module did not self-register.
at Error (native)
at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:450:18)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
at require (module.js:385:17)
at bindings (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bonescript/node_modules/ffi/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bonescript/node_modules/ffi/node_modules/ref/lib/ref.js:5:47)
at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
```

Even I try `npm rebuild` the error still exist, also I try it remove the 
node_modules folder and `npm install` again, the problem still exist, can I know what's wrong with this?

Comment: have you tried running commands with sudo? also check that rebuild and install gives no errors.

Comment: Ya, but it keep looping with these lines
make: Leaving directory `/usr/demo/node_modules/ws/build'
make: Entering directory `/usr/demo/node_modules/ws/build'
  ACTION Regenerating Makefile

Comment: is your package.json in place? node version?

Comment: yes package.json in place, node v5.0.0

Comment: i'd try to: update to latest, delete node modules, recreate the package.json with npm init (saving it somewhere) clean cache and npm install again. ultra combo :D